# How to look for values based on case insensitive keys in HashMap using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

I have below logic where I have passed an JSON object and an HashMap :-

```
export const modifyKeys = (obj: { [x: string]: any; }, myMap: any) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
        if (myMap !== undefined) {
            if (myMap.has(key)) {
                var fieldName = myMap.get(key);
                //console.log('Field Name::', fieldName);
                obj[fieldName] = obj[key];
                delete obj[key];
                if (typeof obj[fieldName] === "object") {
                    modifyKeys(obj[fieldName], myMap);
                }
            }else{
                delete obj[key];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My map contains key-value and in this JSON object, I will look for corresponding attributes to match with the key and perform some operations like replacing that attribute by the value of HashMap and if no match found then delete that attribute itself from the JSON object. But the problem is right now the key has to be case-sensitive because of which some data gets skipped. I want to consider the case-insensitive during the match. For instance, for JSON object like this

```
{
 firstName: 'Vinod',
 LastName: 'Kumar'
}
```

and with Map containing the key-value as FirstName-f_name, the match should happened and final object should become like this

```
{
 f_name: 'Vinod',
 LastName: 'Kumar'
}
```

Any suggestion guys, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to loop through keys in myMap... but the following should work providing you dont have any keys whose only difference is case...   Basically just created normalized keys by using .toLowerCase();

```js
export const modifyKeys = (obj: {[x: string]: any;}, myMap: any) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    var normalizedKey = key.toLowerCase();
    if (myMap !== undefined) {
      var mapKeys = Object.keys(myMap);
      var keyFound = false;
      for (var index = 0; index < mapKeys.length && !keyFound; index++) {
        var mapKey = mapKeys[index];
        var normalizedMapKey = mapKey.toLowerCase();
        if (normalizedMapKey == normalizedKey) {
          var fieldName = myMap[mapKey];
          obj[fieldName] = obj[key];
          delete obj[key];
          if (typeof obj[fieldName] === 'object') {
            modifyKeys(obj[fieldName], myMap);
          }
          keyFound = true;
        }
      }
      if (!keyFound) {
        delete obj[key];
      }
    }
  });
}
```